# Windows Event Viewer: can't find user-started programs

Tags: windows, forensics, logging, monitoring

My problem is as simple as it may look from the beginning. I want to see what programs have been initialized by using the Windows Event Viewer, but the log everybody tells me to use (Security logs, using Event ID 4688) only shows me information about system binaries (e.g. lsass.exe, csrss.exe...).

Is there any log I can visit to monitor the execution of installed programs?

PS: I know there are a lot of alternatives to the Event Viewer, but the lab I'm trying to solve doesn't have any of those tools for the sake of immersiveness (they say).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to enable process auditing in your Windows instance, you can use Group Policy Editor (`gpedit.msc`) or Local Security Policy (`secpol.msc`).

You should configure Security Settings --> Audit Policy --> Audit Process Tracking or use Advanced Audit Policy Configuration --> System Audit Policy --> Detailed Tracking.

After enabling process auditing, Windows will register the following events in Security log:

```
4688 – A new process has been created.
4689 – A process has exited.
```

This is an example of an event (process creation):

```
A new process has been created.
Subject:
            Security ID:                  S-1-5-21-1388294503-2733603710-2753204785-1000
            Account Name:                 Administrator
            Account Domain:               HACKEM
            Logon ID:                     000332DD

Process Information:
            New Process ID:               0000254C
            New Process Name:             C:\Program Files (x86)\Jitsi\Jitsi.exe
            Token Elevation Type:         TokenElevationTypeLimited (3)
            Creator Process ID:           00001010
            Process Command Line:

Token Elevation Type indicates the type of token that was assigned to the new process in accordance with User Account Control policy.

Type 1 is a full token with no privileges removed or groups disabled.  A full token is only used if User Account Control is disabled or if the user is the built-in Administrator account or a service account.

Type 2 is an elevated token with no privileges removed or groups disabled.  An elevated token is used when User Account Control is enabled and the user chooses to start the program using Run as administrator.  An elevated token is also used when an application is configured to always require administrative privilege or to always require maximum privilege, and the user is a member of the Administrators group.

Type 3 is a limited token with administrative privileges removed and administrative groups disabled.  The limited token is used when User Account Control is enabled, the application does not require administrative privilege, and the user does not choose to start the program using Run as administrator.
```

A screenshot of the event log is included:
[image: 4688 Event Log - A new process has been created]